# Is it acceptable to group password characters by category?

Tags: passwords

To ease the wifi PSK key input, I want to group characters by category, to reduce the number of context switches on various devices.

For example

```
HWJt9cR4a3^YEH8^Sj3ix87z^gfD#MuBivJX7UzpMZF8cjw@gsLi$6iRt7ezF##
```

will be turned into

```
^^^#@$##94383877867HWJRYEHSDMBJXUMZFLRFtcajixzgfuivzpcjwgsiitez
```

when grouping, I shuffle categories randomly for each key, e.g. I can get

```
94383877867HWJRYEHSDMBJXUMZFLRFtcajixzgfuivzpcjwgsiitez^^^#@$##
```

or

```
tcajixzgfuivzpcjwgsiitez94383877867HWJRYEHSDMBJXUMZFLRF^^^#@$##
```

instead.

My question is, can you estimate the entropy loss for such transformation? Is this still acceptable for a randomly generated key?

My gut says yes, but I never actually seen this feature in any key generator, even those specialized on wifi/WPA, and it helps *massively* for manual key input on various devices such as TVs and game consoles.

Comment: Nice idea. It will reduce the entropy, but you can offset that by making the key a bit longer. If you're lucky, someone may give you an answer with an actual calculation. What is "acceptable" depends on the network, and most home networks use much shorter keys than your example.

Comment: WPA limits PSK to 63 ASCII characters, so that's the best you can do. Admittedly it's an overkill for a regular wifi setup, and my guess this won't affect the security in any meaningful way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting concept. For a human and from the perspective of a blind brute force, I don't see a significant issue with doing this.

The transformation you propose does significantly shrink the number of possible passphrase variations, and this is easy to take into account in order to perform a smarter brute force attack. That is provided the attacker is aware of the type of transformation and the spacing between categories. In essence you're relying on the obscurity of your methodology to maximise its effectiveness, and whilst obscurity does have its place, it should not be relied on (it's just a bad principle).

I can venture a guess of how the key space reduces with a very simple example - 5 digits (10) and 5 lower case letters (26) and 5 symbols (considering only 10 possible samples):

- No sectioning: 46^15 = 10^26
- Strict sectioning: 10^5 * 26^5 * 10^5 = 10^17

This means the total number of combinations without sectioning is 10000000000 times larger than the number of passphrases you can generate with sectioning.

Comment: In the strict sectioning, I think it should be multiply not add?

Comment: You are correct, let me edit the post.

Comment: A useful comparison to improve your answer would be the length of equal security passwords with and without sectioning.

Comment: I am taking a randomly generated passphrase as a base, which does not guarantee specific number of characters for any category (except having at least one of each), so you'd still be force to guess about the section sizes and order, but I'm not sure how to quantify this

Comment: Sure, this was a sample to highlight how you are limiting the number of possible variations. I know it is not what you would use, it is only a simplified example.